# Angular ng-style does not update in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, dom

I've built a pretty simple carousel in Angular using CSS animations and it works great in Chrome, but when I decided to test in Safari I noticed the click and drag functionality does not work. I've been struggling with this for the past few days and I hope you can help.

After some investigation, I've come to the conclusion that the `$scope.getAnimatorStyles` method is being properly invoked but the `ng-style="getAnimatorStyles()"` is not updating the dom as expected.

I've tried to following with no luck.

- Force a scope update by calling `$scope.$apply()`
- Watch `$scope.animationDelay` and apply the styles directly to the DOM
- Force the browser to reflow by calling `.offsetHeight`
- Update `$scope.animationDelay` inside `$timeout`

The odd thing is that if I apply the styles to the document body it works which makes me think that Angular is doing something weird to the directive.

Here is a codepen with the slider code: http://codepen.io/jabes/pen/KNpEbq

Any help is very much appreciated.

#### Edit #1:

So I've made some progress by forcing a reflow. On click and drag I change the display property which works somewhat, but this also resets the animation so this is not a solution. I've also taken a couple GIFs to illustrate how the browser is not rendering properly.

Here is Chrome (http://recordit.co/fcmIdVntjC), notice how the animator element is moving along with the cards and when I change the delay property it also changes position along with the cards.

Here is Safari (http://recordit.co/V2bwhL877J), notice how the animator element is static while the cards animate and when I change the delay it moves but the cards do not change position.

#### Edit #2:

Okay so I've isolated the HTML/CSS and stripped out all Angular and JavaScript and the problem still persists. Safari does not update the animation position when animation-delay is changed in the element's style property.

#### Edit #3:

This issue seems unrelated to Angular altogether. I have created another post that illustrates a css animation bug in Safari: [CSS Animation Delay Bug In Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535558/css-animation-delay-bug-in-safari)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing a `console.log` on the style object that is being generated and returned by the `getAnimatorStyles()` function?  Perhaps there's something happening there that you're not expecting.

Also, can you copy/paste that same style object back into the template definition, just to test it and see if anything different happens?

When I'm totally stuck, I always double-check the basics just to rule them out.  Sometimes, it is just a basic error that we overlook because we're looking for a more difficult problem which doesn't exist.

Comment: I have made some progress but it's not a complete solution. To force the browser to reflow I'm setting `display:none` then `display:block` after a change is made to `$scope.animationDelay` which seems to work but now it resets the animation position and it jumps.